# Get detailed information on FileSystemEventArgs.ChangeType

Tags: c#

I using the FileWatcher Class to locate changes on Files in a specific Folder.

I managed to detect Changes on Files but not detailed Information.

On the WatcherChangeTypes Enumeration Page

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6xf43e0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

they write the Change Type detects the changes include: changes to size, attributes, security settings, last write, and last access time.

Is there a way to detect which kind of change happened?

Thats the Event handler method i use.

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " Change Type: " + e.ChangeType);

}
```

Thank you in advance

Case

Comment: What is unclear about e.ChangeType?

Comment: it doesn't specify which change occured, only that a change occured.

Comment: Exactly. Say as a example the LastAccessTime Propertie changed. It dispatch the event which only say ChangeType = Change. I got the same if lets say the filesize change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is a `FileSystemWatcher` with a `NotifyFilter` tuned to a specific type of change(s):

```
var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\");
fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess;
fsw.Changed += OnFileAccessed

private static void OnFileAccessed( object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e )
{
    ...
}
```

If you wanted different events to fire based on different change triggers, I believe you would need multiple watchers on the same file.

See [FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more.

Comment: I see you point.
Right now in my Notify Filter is this:

watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Attributes;

I try the way, with multiple watchers with single NotifyFilter Parameters.

Thank you for this answer :)